# Why is this nested?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nested-models

Is it fair to compare two models one with one of the predictors treated as a continuous variable and in the other, you treat it as categorical variable using ANOVA? Can we call the first model nested under the second?

Answer (score 1):

*Nested* models are models where all regressors in model A are also included in model B, as-is, without transformations. Thus, a model with a main effect $X$ would be nested in a model with an interaction term $X\times Y$ - *as long as the main effect is also present in the interaction model*. If the second model does not contain the main effect, then the first model is not nested in the second any more.

In your example, your models will *not* be nested. Unless, that is, one model contains the continuous predictor and the other one contains *both* the continuous and the categorical one - but I assume you don't want to do this.

And you cannot compare non-nested models using ANOVA. ANOVA investigates how much *additional* variance is explained in a larger model compared to a smaller model nested within it.

However, you could of course compare different non-nested models using information criteria (AIC, BIC etc.), or as to their performance in cross-validation.

[Note that categorizing continuous variables is usually a bad idea.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/16565/1352) See also [here](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/Main/CatContinuous).