# How to find the covariance matrix?

Tags: covariance, matrix

I have some trouble understanding the concept of a covariance matrix. For instance, I'm going over this question that says: assume that we have U1, U2 and U3 as independent zero-mean, unit-variance Gaussian random variables. Furthermore, we have X = U1, Y = U1 + U2, and Z = U1 + U2 + U3. We're asked to find the covariance matrix for (X,Y,Z).

I just require some guidance/hints on how to solve this sort of a problem. And I'd really appreciate any help on this matter.

Comment: Let's start by focusing your question: is your trouble over understanding how to arrange the three covariances into a matrix or is it in understanding covariance or is it in computing covariances of such (linear) combinations of Normal variables?

Comment: @whuber I believe it's a combination of the first and the third one. :(

Comment: I have done some searching.  The most effective keywords were ["covariance linear combination"](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=covariance+linear+combination).  The answer at  http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/38722, found with that search, directly and thoroughly addresses the third issue.  I don't believe anyone has asked about the first issue. Please, then, edit your question to focus on the issue of arranging covariances into a matrix. When you do so, add the [tag:self-study] tag.

Comment: Ah... an answer to the first issue can be found at http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/56235 (the result of searching for ["covariance matrix"](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=covariance+matrix).  It looks, then, like every aspect of your question already has an answer somewhere on our site :-).  Is that the case or is there something that still needs to be addressed?

Comment: @whuber Thank you so much! That's exactly what I was looking for. :)