# can I use PCA and PAF on Kendall's and Spearman's correlation matrix?

Tags: pca, factor-analysis, ordinal-data, spearman-rho, kendall-tau

I have a [dataset](https://github.com/maxheld83/keyneson) of `77` items, ranked by `17` people, with many ties (actually: Q-sorted under a forced quasi-normal distribution in 15 bins). I am interested in common patterns of sorting items *across* people, so I want some exploratory factor analysis (PCA or PAF, probably) with *items* as cases, and *people* as variables (I know, it's odd - it's called Q Methodology.

The end result should be factor *scores* on these items, as "ideal-typical" ways to rank order these items. (Again, that's not me, that's Q).

I *want* to assume / preserve the *ordinal* nature of this data, so that leaves Spearman's or Kendall's as correlation coefficients for the correlation matrix. (I'm vaguely aware of Polychoric correlations, but I have no idea how that works, so I'd rather not touch it).

Two questions:

1. *Can* I use PAF and/or PCA on a Spearman's and/or Kendall's correlation coefficient?
2. How would I have to interpret the results *differently* (from a Pearson's based PAF/PCA) – if at all?

I know there are some answers *around* this issue, but there remains disagreement in answers and comments, as well as the literature. Also, the Q-circumstances are a bit special (or not, I don't know).

- This [A](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/62989/3277) seems to suggest Spearman works (no word on Kendall), though with different interpretation.
- This [Q](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/22520/3277) on SSCP seems to have to do with it.
- This [A](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/141669/3277) says "classic (linear) factor analysis" is only for Pearson's
- [Basilevsky 2009](https://books.google.de/books?id=uvZkWmRTZhUC&pg=PA517&lpg=PA517&dq=principal%20components%20analysis%20kendall%27s%20tau&source=bl&ots=T4O25OS-LN&sig=125F3IEyzrZumFEtkJvwL8tjvx8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=vKMKVdLILMTeU_m5gJgJ&ved=0CF0Q6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=principal%20components%20analysis%20kendall's%20tau&f=false) says "A Factor analysis can be based on a correlation matrix using Kendall's tau. Nothing new of major importance arises with respect to the interpretation of the results (...).

Ps.: since this (also) pertains to Q-Methodology, I'd appreciate if someone could add `qmethod` as a tag; see [QMethod](http://qmethod.org/about) for a description and more.