# Matrix multiplication to find correlation matrix

Tags: correlation, mathematical-statistics, matrix, linear-algebra, correlation-matrix

In [this book](http://lnfm1.sai.msu.ru/~rastor/Books/Skillicorn-Understanding_complex_datasets_data_mining_with_matrix_decompositions.pdf) on matrix factorizations, the author states the following, which I don't find to be true empirically. Is it true and under what conditions?

[image]

**ADD:** Trying to recreate the answer in R, what is the issue?

```
> D<-matrix(c(7,1,4,5,2,2,4,5,5,2,5,1,7,8,0,7),nrow=4,ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
> D
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    7    1
[2,]    4    5
[3,]    2    2
[4,]    4    5
> cor(D)
           [,1]       [,2]
[1,]  1.0000000 -0.3333333
[2,] -0.3333333  1.0000000
> 
> D[,1]<-D[,1]-mean(D[,1])
> D[,2]<-D[,2]-mean(D[,2])
> 
> D[,1]<-D[,1]/norm(as.matrix(D[,1]))
> D[,2]<-D[,2]/norm(as.matrix(D[,2]))
> D
            [,1]       [,2]
[1,]  0.50000000 -0.3214286
[2,] -0.04545455  0.2500000
[3,] -0.40909091 -0.1785714
[4,] -0.04545455  0.2500000
> t(D)%*%D
           [,1]       [,2]
[1,]  0.4214876 -0.1103896
[2,] -0.1103896  0.2602041
```

Comment: Of your possible interest: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/22520/3277.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the author is simply *handy-wavy* there. I believe it is assumed that the columns of $A$ have norm 1 and mean 0.

$A^TA$ is a [Gram matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix). Given you are using random variables to construct $A$, $A^TA$ is approximately proportional to the covariance matrix (scale by $n$ the number of variables). The correlation matrix is simply the scaled version of the covariance matrix. Clearly if your random variables in the columns of $A$ are already normalized to unit-norm then $A^TA$ does not need any further normalization and it is immediately a correlation matrix.

For example using MATLAB:

```
 % Set the seed and generate a random matrix
 rng(123);        
 A = randn(10,3);
 A'*A

 % ans =
 %  4.867589606955550  -3.004809945345502  -1.615373090426428
 % -3.004809945345502   5.356131932084330  -0.457643222208441
 % -1.615373090426428  -0.457643222208441   5.574303027408192.

 % Normalized now all the variables to have unit norm and mean zeros

 A = A - repmat(mean(A),10,1);
 A(:,1) = A(:,1)./norm(A(:,1));
 A(:,2) = A(:,2)./norm(A(:,2));
 A(:,3) = A(:,3)./norm(A(:,3));
 A'*A

 % ans =
 %  1.000000000000000  -0.568373671796724  -0.336996715690262
 % -0.568373671796724   1.000000000000000  -0.052272607974969
 % -0.336996715690262  -0.052272607974969   1.000000000000000
```

If we wanted to make the columns of $A$ orthogonal too, we would orthonormalize $A$. In that case we would do a [Gram-Schmidt process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) on $A$; a process relating to *a lot of wonderful things* eg. [Givens rotations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Givens_rotation), [Householder transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation), etc.)

Comment: This is great, thank you!! I am curious if you program in R? I cant produce the correlation matrix following these steps and I wonder if my problem is software related? I added to the original question the code I was using.

Comment: I saw your code. `norm(A(:,1))` in MATLAB is the Euclidean norm (norm-2). `norm(as.matrix(D[,1]))` in R is the maximum absolute norm (norm-1). You want to use: `norm(as.matrix(D[,1]), '2')`. More information can be found by typing `?norm` in R terminal.