# How to make correlation coefficient account for linear transformation?

Tags: correlation

The Pearson correlation coefficient is scale-invariant.  Therefore the correlation $cor(x,y)$ remains the same if $x$ or $y$ is linearly transformed (i.e., $x - 1$ or $2x$).

I am interested in a correlation coefficient that **is** sensitive to linear transformation.  If $cor(x,y) = 1.00$, I want $cor(x-1, y) < 1$.  In other words, I want a strict correlation coefficient that requires $x = y$ in order for $r = 1.00$.

One idea I had was to modify the covariance term $\Sigma (x - \bar x)(y - \bar y)$ to shrink when the means of $x$ and $y$ diverge, but I am uneasy about creating a monster statistic with intractable properties.  In principle, I am looking for something like $\Sigma (x - \bar x)(y - \bar y) - (|\bar x - \bar y |)$.

Is there an existing method to achieve this type of "strict" correlation coefficient?

Comment: How about a distance measure?

Comment: See identity coefficient and similarity ratio mentioned in https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/22520/3277. There are other alternatives to r as well.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_correlation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are (at least) two correlation-type measures that measure the absolute agreement between two measurements (i.e., they will only be equal to 1 when $x = y$). The first is the [intraclass correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intraclass_correlation) and the other is the [concordance correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concordance_correlation_coefficient). They often give very similar results. For example:

```
x <- c(2,4,3,6,8)
y <- 1 + x
n <- length(x)

s2x <- sum((x - mean(x))^2) / n
s2y <- sum((x - mean(x))^2) / n
sxy <- sum((x - mean(x)) * (y - mean(y))) / n

cor(c(x,y),c(y,x)) # ICC          
[1] 0.8977505

2*sxy / (s2x + s2y + (mean(x) - mean(y))^2) # concordance correlation
[1] 0.9027237
```

Comment: You may have access to https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0169555X05003740 which surveyed not just concordance correlation but the general problem of assessing agreement.

Comment: @Wolfgang Thank you for your helpful answer.  ICC fits the bill.  I like your clever implementation using cor().  Where can I read more about this implementation?  It is slightly different from other implementations of ICC.

Comment: @NickCox Thanks.  I found this article to be the most helpful: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4913118/

Comment: @Wolfgang If I may add a follow-up question: What type of ICC does your answer implement?  Based on the readings I am looking for ICC with two-way random effects, absolute agreement, and single rater, aka ICC(2,1).

Comment: The one that is estimated by `cor(c(x,y),c(y,x))` is the ICC(1,1). This estimator goes back to Fisher. You can also use the ANOVA approach to estimate it. The two approaches often give very similar estimates. If you want to estimate the ICC(2,1), then use the ANOVA approach.

Comment: @Wolfgang Thanks.  This is very helpful. All the best.