# Benchmarking a clustering algorithm

Tags: clustering, references, validation

### Intro

I built a clustering algorithm for a specific problem I have.
The clustering algorithm wasn't my main goal, I just had to be able to separate the data into clusters prior to further processing, and I wanted to see if I could cluster the data so that I can later run my further processing on unlabeled data.

### Some Details

It turns out that it worked great. However, my dataset might be too small an I might just overfit. So my question is can you point me toward standard benchmark datasets to compare my algorithm against?

Some more details:
My algorithm is designed to cluster data of the following form:

- Each sample is a block (or sequence) of binary values.
- All samples are of the same size (same number of bits).
- Samples can be quite long (up to about a thousand bits each).

I presume that each sample originates from some (unknown) distribution and that each cluster originates from a different distribution. In a sense, my problem is very similar to a GMM model with a maximum likelihood of classification. The main differences are that the distribution isn't gaussian (variables are discrete), and the GMM would perform very poorly for distributions with a dimension of 1000 due to the curse of dimensionality.
Somehow (I'm not sure yet exactly how), my algorithm circumferences this problem, and I wonder if it is because of the dataset.

### My Questions

1. Are there standard algorithms that try to accomplish the same goal or at least try to cluster binary sequences of relevant lengths that I can benchmark my algorithm against?
2. Are there any datasets that I could use (binary sequences) in order to test my algorithm against further data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative methods: Any distance-based method - such as Single, Complete, Average Linkage of Hierarchical clustering or Partitioning Around Medoids clustering - can be used with an appropriate distance on binary sequences, such as Simple Matching or Jaccard. There is also a standard mixture model for such data that is usually called latent class model, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_class_model. Clusters are modelled as subsets within which variables are independent ("local independence"). The R-package `poLCA` can do this. One could also use distances, run multidimensional scaling on them, and then run a GMM on the MDS output as is done in our R-package `prabclus`, function `prabclust`. There's also `BayesLCA` for Bayesian latent class analysis.

I add that somebody once told me that despite originally being designed for continuous data, k-means can work well with binary sequences (if the dimension is not very low - not sure about very big). I think I've never tried it, but this person may be right and it could be worth a try.

The `prabclus`-package has example data sets `veronica` and `kykladspecreg`, although both come without ground truth in the package. (I have something of a ground truth vector for `veronica`, and you can contact me off site about it, however these "true species" are not necessarily reliable.) `poLCA` also has example data sets, but I don't know whether these have ground truth information.

Some general considerations regarding cluster benchmarking are here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.10496
You may also think about generating artificial data with known truth for benchmarking.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! You’ve given me some good HW :) I’ll go over these and perhaps contact you offsite as suggested.

Comment: Very nice answer. Just to remark, for a reader not well versed, that `run multidimensional scaling on them, and then run a GMM on the MDS output` implies creating a points x features (euclidean dimensions) data out if a distance matrix, because GMM will call for such data as input.

Comment: `k-means can work well with binary sequences` It could. And in text analysis, as you know, they often apply K-means to binary data normalized (i.e., k-means implied to be done on cosine similarity = on chord distance). The theoretical doubt remains: are we in the right to ever compute centroids directly in the "granular" space such as defined by binary features? Can and when "mean" is a valid concept for categorical data, including binary as categorical?

Comment: @ttnphns Means of binary variables are relative frequencies, therefore estimated probabilities. I think the problem is if we have several dummy variables for categories with originally more than two values, as k-means treats the variables as independent, which they are not in this case.

Comment: Christian, the point that the mean of a binary variable has a (probabilistic) meaning does not automatically and happily make the dichotomous scale suitable for k-means or other analysis of metric scales: the meaning is an epi-phenomenon, a statistic. I'm just touching the question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/16335/3277) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/40637/3277).