# What is a good data reduction technique for nominal or dummy variable data?

Tags: r, categorical-data, factor-analysis

I have a large data set with nominal and dummy variables. What's a good data reduction technique to use? [Factor analysis cannot be used here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/184708/interpreting-factor-loadings-and-calculating-factor-scores#comment350816_184708), can it?

Bonus points if there is an `R` package for this. Extra bonus points if this technique can be used with the `survey` package. My data is from a complex survey, which I am analyzing using the `survey` package.

Comment: Why do you think factor analysis cannot be used?

Comment: That's what someone told me in another thread: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/184708/interpreting-factor-loadings-and-calculating-factor-scores#comment350816_184708 Apparently, FA needs the data to be continuous, while my data is all nominal variables, which I convert to dummy variables. So is it generally agreed that FA cannot be used with my data? Or is it just the position of some?

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to assume that some latent categories--as opposed to latent continuous dimensions (as in factor analysis)--underlie your observed variables, you could use latent class analysis using the `poLCA` package (continuous and categorical predictors are both accommodated). However, I am not sure if `poLCA` can be used in conjunction with the `survey` package. Also, `poLCA` only allows you to model latent categories as outcomes of, as opposed to predictors of, other variables (unlike the latent class analysis capabilities of Mplus).