# Encoding of categorical variables for machine learning: binary vs. one-hot followed by PCA

Tags: machine-learning, categorical-data, pca, data-preprocessing, many-categories

Edit: changed the title, removed call for opinions

[This post](http://www.kdnuggets.com/2015/12/beyond-one-hot-exploration-categorical-variables.html) compares several methods of encoding categorical data. Binary encoding (convert categories to integers, then to binary; assign each digit a separate column) seems to provide the best combination of predictive accuracy and dimensionality control.

However, the top answer to [this post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/9443/when-to-use-one-hot-encoding-vs-labelencoder-vs-dictvectorizor) advocates applying PCA to one-hot encoded (convert categories to integers; assign each integer value a separate column, e.g. 5 = 0, 0, 0, 0, 1) data to isolate the most descriptive dimensions within.  This would seem to be even better, dimension-wise, than binary encoding, without the associated distortion of distances.  Has anyone compared binary vs. one-hot + PCA?

Comment: I think you need to explain what you mean by "binary encoding", & perhaps by "one-hot encoding".

Comment: For categorical variables with many levels, see [principled-way-of-collapsing-categorical-variables-with-many-levels](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/146907/principled-way-of-collapsing-categorical-variables-with-many-levels), which offers other solutions than the two offered here, like the fused lasso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that by binary encoding you mean the one [explained here](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/types-of-categorical-data-encoding-schemes-a5bbeb4ba02b), I would advice against using it. Seems an ill-advised idea, I will explain why.  First explaining shortly the idea:

Suppose (only for simplicity) your categorical variable have $p=2^q$ levels, for the example I take $q=3$. Then code the levels with the binary numbers $0=000_2, 1=001_2, 2=010_2, 3=011_2, 4=100_2, 5=101_2, 6=110_2, 7=111_2$. Then, for each of the 3 bits, introduce one column in the design matrix, recording just that bit (so 0 or 1.) What is wrong with this? The 8 possible levels is represented in a 3-dimensional linear subspace, introducing (many!) linear restrictions! Those restrictions will depend on how you associate  levels to binary numbers. In short: **do not ever use this idea**. That makes your main question here moot ...

About applying PCA to a matrix of one-hot vectors encoding a categorical variable, there is many posts here, search, I don't know. But I would in its case looking into using correspondence analysis in place of PCA, but see [Doing principal component analysis or factor analysis on binary data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16331/doing-principal-component-analysis-or-factor-analysis-on-binary-data).