# Data Preprocessing before using PCA for unsupervised learning (clustering)

Tags: machine-learning, dimensionality-reduction

I'm wondering whether to use OneHotEncoding before using PCA.

I did some googling and it seems the answer is no, because PCA doesn't work well on binary data (This is the [source](https://www.kaggle.com/general/21449))

I just want to make sure my current understanding, that :

1. Numerical features should be standardized (by `StandardScaler`) before applying PCA
2. Categorical and ordinal features should be encoded to Integers (by `LabelEncoder`)
3. Related to the 2nd point : Categorical features shouldn't use OneHotEncoding (by `get_dummies`)

Please kindly enlighten me

Thanks for the help

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16331/doing-principal-component-analysis-or-factor-analysis-on-binary-data.  I believe that addresses (3).  Question (1) is answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/53/pca-on-correlation-or-covariance.  (2) is hard to follow: if you *don't* encode your data numerically, then how do you propose to perform any kind of numerical analysis?

Comment: To pt. 2. PCA is a method for quantitative variables, not categorical (nominal or ordinal). There exist Multiple correspondence analysis (MCA) which is like PCA, but is for nominal data. Categorical PCA (CatPCA) is a more general technique which allows ordinal variables and mixed-type variables.