# Scaled vs non-scaled PCA, which is more accurate?

Tags: pca

So in this post:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/16335/78575

The author explains a difference of scaling vs not scaling PCA. The two results differ quite a bit on the same data.

Which one then is more accurate and how to infer the accuracy and the need for scaling or not?

Comment: What do you mean by "accurate" here?

Comment: @Dougal Which one describes the predictive power of variables more accurately?