# Comparing distribution A to B and C

Tags: probability, distributions, multivariate-analysis, discrete-data, kullback-leibler

I have three discrete probability distributions, A, B and C. They are all measuring P(X) under different circumstances. I suspect that A is more similar to B than it is to C. I know that I can compare the difference between distributions with KL divergence, but how can I test whether the difference between A-B is less than the difference between A-C?

Comment: You have a tough problem, because statistical and mathematical theory will not decide the answer: you are assuming there is a relevant way to compare distributions so that "less than" has meaning.  *What* meaning it might have is up to you to decide: that's not something we can tell you--although we can provide some guidance, if you would explain how you intend to interpret the result.

Comment: You seem to answer your own question: by comparing the two KL-divergences. Of course that means you're committing to defining "difference between" as "KL-divergence from".

Comment: Rather than comparing the distributions as a whole, can you not compare specific aspects of the disrubutions, captured by relevant quantiles or functions of quantiles? This might give you more insights into where the distributions differ (e.g., tails).

Answer (score 1):

You already got some hints in comments, and a request for more information, which you didn't give us. Here are some thoughts:

Observations on three discrete variables, presumably defined on the same categories, can be represented as a contingency table. Then you do a correspondence analysis, see [Interpreting 2D correspondence analysis plots](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3270/interpreting-2d-correspondence-analysis-plots).  The results can be presented graphically, and the three variables can be compared with the so-called chisquare distance.  A similar graphical analysis can probably be based on the KL divergence. To say more we need more context.